# How do I create a plot a time series graph of the monthly growth in nominal exchange rates in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, graph

i'm trying to plot against time but the time in my dataframe has become the index
is there a way to plot against the index?

Comment: Welcome to the site. [Please do not post pictures of your code.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.